# query to sum a field from access database with int datatype

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

There is a field named `qty`. I want to sum multiple rows with the same invoice number.

```
String sql = "select sum(qty) from pur_invo_tran where invo_no='"+dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value+"' and doi=#"+Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString())+"#";

OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
con.ConnectionString = constr;
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
OleDbDataReader Reader = null;

try
{
    con.Open();
    int b = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = b.ToString("## ## ## ###.##").Trim().Replace(" ", ",");
    con.Close();
}
catch (Exception ee)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error..." + ee.Message);
}
```

Comment: my invoice number is `56'; drop table pur_invo_tran; --`

Comment: also, what happens when you run that code you just pasted?  I assume it does something other than give you the sum you want.

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of rows affected which is definitely not the sum of invoices and probably not what you want to set the grid cell value to.

Comment: Use parameters... The current version of your query is using a date without specifying the format. Likely either `invo_no` (which is using string delimiters) or that date has the wrong format.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:** Change `ExecuteNonQuery` to be `ExecuteScalar` to put the sum into `b`. If `qty` is not an `int`, you probably need to change the type of `b` (and the cast when assigning it) to use that type.

**Explanation:** `ExecuteNonQuery` is for things like INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE: hence "non-query". SELECT is usually used with `ExecuteReader`, but there is a special case where you only want the first value from the first row: `ExecuteScalar`, which makes sense in this scenario, since you are summing all of a set of values into a single total.

**Other tips...**

1. OleDbConnection, OleDbCommand and OleDbDataReader (*which is unused, but while I'm making this point...*) are all IDisposable so each should be in a `using` block. Once you've done that you don't need to call Close on the connection, since the implicit Dispose will call Close for you.
2. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (this is the point being made in the comment by SamIAm). Avoid this by avoiding string concatenation to create your query: use SQL parameters.
3. `b.ToString("## ## ## ###.##").Trim().Replace(" ", ",");` The `Trim` is redundant since you've just specified the format, and it won't start or end with spaces. Rather than do the `Replace`, why not just format it correctly in the first place, by putting commas in the format string rather than spaces. Or go a step further and consider using the [standard format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) of `N2` or even `C2` (since it's a currency amount) this will use standard numeric or currency formatting for the current culture of the application.

Comment: even after changing ExecuteNonQuery to ExecuteScalar its throwing "specified cast not valid" exception

Comment: @Sachin ExecuteScalar returns an object, so remove the cast, and change `b` to be an `object` rather than `int`. Put a breakpoint after that line, then run the code to hit that breakpoint, and use the debugger to see what type `b` *actually* is. You'll find that it is a different type than `int`... if so then change `b` to be that type, and put the cast back in.

Answer (score 0):

If `Cells[0]` contains text, then:

```
doi=#"+Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value).ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd")+"#"
```

If it holds a *DateTime* value, then only formatting is needed:

```
doi=#"+dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd")+"#"
```

If `invo_no` is numeric, then no quotes:

```
invo_no="+dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value+"
```